# How can I destroy a GameObject that I instantiate in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that spawns 2 GameObject that are clones of 2 prefabs, an enemy prefab, and a player prefab:

```cs
GameObject PlayerGO =player;
playerUnit = PlayerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();
Instantiate(player, PlayerStation);
GameObject EnemyGO = Instantiate(enemy, EnemyStation);
enemyUnit = EnemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();
```

And the clones are called "PlayerGO" and "EnemyGO" respectively.

Now, the idea of the code is that when a battle starts, both the player and enemy spawn in their positions and engage in a fight, but, the problem comes when I enter another battle, because the enemy of the 1st battle is still there, and not only that, but now I have to players at the same time. I tried using this code:

```cs
Destroy(enemy);
```

To get rid of the object, but it only destroys the original instance of the enemy object, not the clone which is still in the hierarchy. I tried using Destroy(EnemyGO) but the code doesn't allow me to do so and suggests using "enemy" instead (which, doesn't work), I also tried with "Destroy(Instantiate(enemy, EnemyStation));", but that also didn't work

How can I destroy the clone?

Comment: If you're storing the enemies in a list, can't you iterate over the list and call `Destroy`?

Comment: You have to provide more code (full classes). From your little piece of code I can only guess, that you only have a local reference to your instantiated GameObjects, which makes destroying them in another method impossible.

Comment: "Destroy(enemyGO);" should work. Can you post the error you are getting? Judging by the code it looks like you are not saving a reference to the game object and are getting a null object exception or your compiler is getting an undefined symbol exception. Calling Destroy(enemy) will destroy the prefab (or original instance). Destroy(Instantiate(enemy, EnemyStation)); will create a third enemy and immediately destroy it. Destroy(enemyUnity) will delete the enemyUnit component from your enemy game object.

Answer (score 0):

In the prefab of the enemy, have a script that Destroys itself by haveing `Destroy(gameObject)`. If the enemy detects a collision then trigger the script. If you want the player to trigger the script then use `yourGameobjectVariableToTheEnemy.GetComponent(SelfDestruct)().selfDestruct`(the first SelfDesruct is the script name and the second is the function name).